# gpu optimization when multiplying by powers of 2 in a shader

Tags: optimization, gpu, shader

Do modern GPUs optimize multiplication by powers of 2 by doing a bit shift? For example suppose I do the following in a shader:

```
float t = 0;
t *= 16;
t *= 17;
```

Is it possible the first multiplication will run faster than the second?

Comment: Theas are [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) types. A multiplication can't be handled by a simple bit shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point multiplication cannot be done by bit shift. Howerver, in theory floating point multiplication by power of 2 constants *can* be optimized. Floating point value is normally stored in the form of  `S * M * 2 ^ E`, where `S` is a sign, `M` is mantissa and `E` is exponent. Multiplying by a power of 2 constant can be done by adding/substracting to the exponent part of the `float`, without modifying the other parts. But in practice, I would bet that on GPUs a generic multiply instruction is always used.

I had an interesting observation regarding the power of 2 constants while studying the disassembly output of the PVRShaderEditor (PowerVR GPUs). I have noticed that a certain range of power of 2 constants ([2^(-16), 2^10] in my case), use special notation, e.g. C65, implying that they are predefined. Whereas arbitrary constants, such as 3.0 or 2.3, use shared register notation (e.g. SH12), which implies they are stored as a uniform and probably incur some setup cost. Thus using power of 2 constants may yield some optimizational benefit at least on some hardware.